# Store multiple lists from one function together

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get something like a timestamp from a SQL database (it's no timestamp but just text, this is because it can be more then 24 hours) anyway; I get this data from the SQL database and I want to count all these queries together, so I do an explode function to split these in to three pieces (hours, minutes, seconds) in an array.

Now the problem: when I run this function it needs to come all in one array, what I get now is that the array only can contain the last element. I think its a pretty simple question but I've been searching for hours an can't find it (I think just because I'm new to the PHP language). Thanks in advance!

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT tijd FROM gespeeldeTijd";   // get data with sql query
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  // do a while loop to fetch all data to an array
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myArray[] = $row["tijd"];
    }
} else { // if there are no results
    echo "0 results";
}


$array_product = [];

function myfunction($value)  //function to do to evry part of the array
{

    $array_product[] = explode(":",$value);   // split the time in hours, 
 minutes, seconds
    return $array_product;

}

array_walk($myArray,"myfunction"); // walk trough evry part of the array
print_r($array_product);

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$array_product` is out of scope inside myfunction. Right now you create a new array inside your function which is immediately discarded when the function ends. If you want to refer to your main array_product variable, you have to import it using `global`. And there's no need for the `return` statement, it goes nowhere.

```
function myfunction($value)  //function to do to every part of the array
{
    global $array_product; //import the variable from the global scope
    $array_product[] = explode(":",$value);   // split the time in hours, minutes, seconds

}
```

See https://eval.in/989726 for a working demo.

P.S. Maybe someone can come up with a nicer way to do this task without using globals (it's not a very clean solution), but that's the quick fix for your current code.

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick answer! now i get something like this "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 00 [2] => 00 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 04 [1] => 00 [2] => 00 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 02 [1] => 00 [2] => 00 ) )" is there a way it comes in one array?

Comment: Technically that is one array. It just happens to contain several arrays within it (the result of the multiple explode statements). And this list of lists is a structure which means you can easily distinguish which of the fragments of time belong with each other. What other result were you hoping for, and why? This output seems quite logical.

Comment: it started to look a little bit an array in array, ad something an array in an array in an array and so on. I thought if it looked like this it was much more simple to do math with it. like this ( Array(  [0] => Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 00 [2] => 00  [3] => 04 [4] => 00 [5] => 00 )

Comment: What kind of maths did you want to do? Really I think it's simpler my way because you easily know which element of the sub array is hours (always element 0), which is minutes (1), seconds (2) whereas in your structure you have to have more code to find every 3rd element to know that. Or maybe, depending on the precise requirements it's better actually to parse the original values as DateTimes and use that class to help with the calculations, I don't know, depends exactly what you had in mind.

Comment: yes thats totally true, i programmed a little bit further on your piece of code and it works totally fine! I think that your are absolutly right, the chance to make mistakes is a lot smaller

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you can try this out, this might help you:

```
function getSomething() {
return array(4,5,6);
}

list($x,$y,$z) = getSomething();
```